# add file to tar with chmod +x python

Tags: python, tar, chmod

I have tar.gz file like:

```
tmp/
tmp/picture/
tmp/picture/1.jpg
```

I want to add to this tar.gz file with python file to `tmp/logger.sh` with chmod +x

How can I do that ?

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open('test.tar.gz','w') as f:
    f.add('logger.sh' , arcname='/tmp/logger.sh')
```

That give me tar file /tmp/logger.sh file but remove the rest of files that was in the tar file + I can't set chmod +x to this file

Comment: The `'w'` flag to `open` will definitely overwrite; you want `'a'`. You can use `filter` to override the `TarInfo.mode` but the much simpler and obvious workaround would be to `chmod` the file before adding it to an archive.

Comment: @tripleee Hot to do that? , I can't set `a` for tarfile.open

Comment: Why not? That's what the documentation clearly suggests. If the file doesn't exist already then of course you can't append to it, but then that doesn't fit with your problem description.

Answer (score 2):

The absolutely simplest solution is to (temporarily?) `chmod` the file before adding it.

As you already discovered, `'w'` mode will overwrite any existing file. To update an existing archive, you want to open the file in `'a'` mode instead.

However, unfortunately, the `tarfile` library does not support opening a `gz` file in `a` mode. You can do this if you have an uncompressed file:

```py
import tarfile

def chmodx(tarinfo):
    tarinfo.mode = int('0755', base=8)
    return tarinfo

with tarfile.open('test.tar', 'a'):
    f.add('logger.sh' , arcname='/tmp/logger.sh', filter=chmodx)
```

The nature of `gz` compression is such that you probably simply want to uncompress the file, update it, and then recompress, rather than do it all in one go.  Ideally, you'd want to do this in memory, but that's problematic if the uncompressed tar file is large.

Comment: I tried to work on a solution for tar.gz but there is a bug which I can't quickly figure out. It somehow fails to copy all archive members all of the time. Work in progress: https://ideone.com/0bgM9S

Answer (score 1):

The `mode` may have to be set explicitly like (default is `r`):

```
tarfile.open('test.tar.gz','a')
```

See also [tarfile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) docs.

File permission settings of a `TarInfo` objects can be done [with `TarInfo.mode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarinfo-objects).

**Edit:** Here the long version:

```
 $ python3.8
Python 3.8.0a1 (default, Feb  3 2019, 20:37:37)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tarfile
>>> fh = tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz', 'w')
>>> fh.add("/home/chris/.zshrc")
>>> fh.add("/home/chris/.zcompdump")
>>> fh.list()
[...] home/chris/.zshrc
[...] home/chris/.zcompdump
>>> fh.close()
>>>
>>> fh = tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz', 'a')
>>> fh.add("/home/chris/.bashrc")
>>> fh.list()
[...] home/chris/.zshrc
[...] home/chris/.zcompdump
[...] home/chris/.bashrc
>>>
```

So it works fine just using `a` without the `:gz`.

Comment: That give me the same result, tar.gz with only 1 files , the rest of file that were in that tar.gz removed

Comment: Sorry, should of course be `a` for append, just like all `file.open`. Updated the answer.

Comment: ValueError: mode must be 'r' , 'w', or 'x'

Comment: Works without the `:gz`, only with `a`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to do that is to directly use the tar command like this:

```
import os
#Ici, on a newFilePath=tmp/logger.sh

command = "tar rf {1} {2} --mode=755".format(tarFilePath,newFilePath)
os.system(command)
```